# Fingerprint driver for Lenovo V330-15IKB in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, lenovo

I have a Lenovo V330-15IKB notebook and would like to use the fingerprint reader. How can I configure it?

Here is the output from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:1135 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100 RAPOO Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: [No driver exists](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:06cb-0081), and I’ve not heard any discussion about when or if it will be looked at 

Comment: *How can I configure it?* You can't. Please read and *understand* the first comment. It probably will never work in Linux unless the manufacturer does something about it.